# xsl:matching-substring always returns "false"

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to write a function which gets the domain name from a URL text in XML file i.e www.example.com.

```
 <xsl:function name="fdd:get-domain">
    <xsl:param name="url"/>

    <xsl:analyze-string select="$url" regex="^(.*)://([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?)(/.*)$">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>

        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>

    </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:function>
```

This function always returns `false`. I'm not sure what am I missing in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inside an attribute value every `{` and `}` must be doubled** (in order to distinguish them from the single chars that denote an AVT. Just by doubling the curly braces:

```
^(.*)://([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{{2,3}}(/\S*)?)(/.*)$
```

**with this correction, when called like this**:

```
fdd:get-domain('http://www.abc/cpm/page.aspx')
```

**the result is**:

```
http
```

**I guess that you really want to get the *domain*, as this modified code (both the regex expression and the regex-group index) does:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:fdd="some:fdd">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="fdd:get-domain('http://www.abc.com/cpm/page.aspx')"/>
 </xsl:template>

      <xsl:function name="fdd:get-domain">
        <xsl:param name="url"/>

        <xsl:analyze-string select="$url" regex=
"^(.*)://([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{{2,3}})(/\S*)?(/.*)$">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>

            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>

        </xsl:analyze-string>
     </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
www.abc.com
```

**Update**: As reminded by Michael Kay, the need to duplicate any curly braces can be avoided if the RegEx is specified as the context of a variable and this variable is referenced as an AVT in the `regex` attribute of `xsl:analyze-string` :

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$url" regex="{$vRegEx}"
                    flags="mx" >
```

This has another benefit -- we can split RegEx subexpressions on different lines and even intermix them with comments.

Here is the refactored transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:fdd="some:fdd">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vRegEx">

   ^(.*) <!-- The scheme -->

   ://

   ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}) <!-- The domain -->

   (/\S*)?(/.*)$  <!-- the path and query string -->

 </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:sequence select="fdd:get-domain('http://www.abc.com/cpm/page.aspx')"/>
     </xsl:template>

          <xsl:function name="fdd:get-domain">
            <xsl:param name="url"/>

            <xsl:analyze-string select="$url" regex="{$vRegEx}"
                                flags="mx" >
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>

                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>

            </xsl:analyze-string>
         </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Correct answer. If the doubling of curlies becomes a pain, putting the regex in a variable can help (use `regex="{$regex}"`)

Comment: @MichaelKay: Yes, and another benefit of puttiong the regex in a variable is that then the regex can be presented in parts on different lines (in different text nodes), each preceded by a comment -- something most often needed than not in the case uf writing and understanding RegExes.

Comment: @maheshexp: AVT is "Attribute Value Templates" read about it in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates

Comment: @maheshexp: Yes, this helps a lot. I have built lexers for JSON and for XPath 2.0 and the rather long RegExes are split into small subparts with explaining comments -- huge difference, making this possible.